# jquery remove appended valued on desellect

Tags: jquery, append

I'm getting duplicated valued by using append function. Below is my code

```
$(function () {
    $('.gallery_cont1').on('click',function(){ 
        $('#template-sel').append($(this).find('h2').text()+'<br />');
});
});
```

For the first click (means select) text is adding properly , but for second click (means deselect) previous appended text is not removing.

Did anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `append()` function with `html()` like this

```
$(function () {
    $('.gallery_cont1').on('click',function(){ 
        $('#template-sel').html($(this).find('h2').text()+'<br />');
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried html() it's adding only one. I'm having a multiple select image. Trying to display selected image names.

Answer (score 1):

This will check to see if the HTML of the template-sel element is already equal to the text from the H2 so when it is clicked again it should remove the text.

```
$(function () {
$('.gallery_cont1').on('click',function(){ 
    if($('#template-sel').html()==$(this).find('h2').text()+'<br />')
        $('#template-sel').html('');
    else
        $('#template-sel').html($(this).find('h2').text()+'<br />');
});
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. It's adding last selected value twice. I'm having a multiple select image. Trying to display selected image names.